# Is there any way to change the outline size of a turtle compound shape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a compound shape. What I want now is to change the outline size of this new compound shape.

I have made the shape like this:

```
import turtle

points_1 = [...] # list of points
points_2 = [...] # list of points

shape = turtle.Shape('compound')
poly = turtle.Turtle()
poly.begin_poly()

for point_list in [points_1, points_2]:
    poly.goto(point_list [0][0], point_list[0][1])
    poly.begin_poly()
    for point in point_list[1:]:
        poly.goto(point[0], point[1])
    poly.goto(point_list[0][0], point_list[0][1])
    poly.end_poly()
    shape.addcomponent(poly.get_poly(), '', 'darkgreen')

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.register_shape('my_turtle', shape)
screen.clearscreen()

my_shape = turtle.Turtle()
my_shape.shape('my_turtle')

turtle.done()
```

I tried to change the `pensize` of the poly and my_shape, but none of them worked.

How can I achieve this with a compound shape of multiple polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `shapesize()` method:

```
 shapesize(stretch_wid=None, stretch_len=None, outline=None)
```

For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Shape, Turtle

points_1 = [(10, -25), (10, -5), (-10, -5), (-10, -25)]  # list of points
points_2 = [(10, -5.77), (0, 11.55), (-10, -5.77)]  # list of points

turtle = Turtle()

shape = Shape('compound')

for point_list in [points_1, points_2]:
    turtle.goto(point_list[0])
    turtle.begin_poly()
    for point in point_list[1:]:
        turtle.goto(point)
    turtle.goto(point_list[0])
    turtle.end_poly()
    shape.addcomponent(turtle.get_poly(), '', 'darkgreen')

screen = Screen()
screen.register_shape('my_turtle', shape)
screen.clearscreen()

my_shape = Turtle()
my_shape.shape('my_turtle')

my_shape.shapesize(2, 3, outline=10)

screen.mainloop()
```

To just change the outline width, leave off the other arguments and specify on the `outline=10` argument by name.

PS: The `shapesize()` method also has the alias `turtlesize()` which can be used instead.